# Pentaho Data Integration New Row for Each Deliminated Value in a Column

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a stream with a column with a variable number of semicolon deliminated values with a layout like

activities    ticket_id
1;2;3         1
4;5           2
6;            3
7;8;9;10      4

.  How can I get a new row for ever activity, like this

activity_id   ticket_id
1             1
2             1
3             1
4             2

and so on?

In case I formatted this question wrong, here's an image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the "Split field to rows" step, use the Activities column as the field to split and ";" as the Delimeter.

Remenber that when you have a single value AND the delimeter, the step will output an additional row with an empty string. In this scenario the step will auto adjust the ticket_id column to repeat the values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian, that's more elegant than the JavaScript solution we found later in the business day yesterday

Answer (score 0):

This solution in the screenshot below worked too

[image]